# Trouble using Facebook login in Android project

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to use facebook login in my app.

I've gone through everything except for importing the actual Facebook SDK into my project.

Where I'm encountering trouble is after I download the SDK and move the 'facebook' folder from the SDK folder into my project under a 'libraries' folder. I follow the steps on the Facebook developers site for updating dependencies etc.

After all of this, I can successfully `import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;`

So, I think that I'd be able to use the login button at this point. But apparently I'm wrong, because when I try to use the button in a layout file, I see this:

[image]

When I click 'open class', I'm given the option to 'Attach sources' to the LoginButton.Java file. So I do that, and I choose the 'facebook' from the facebook SDK download as the source.

After I do this, I get errors in the .Java file:

[image]

It seems that the expected parameters and actual arguments for each of the constructors above don't match.

I'm very confused, so all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering problem is a designer issue that's fixed in the latest release 4.2.0. But even without that fix, your app would run. Check out the samples that come with the SDK to see how it works.